# Redirecting an output of command executed using Plink on double-hop SSH session

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

From my Windows system, I'm connecting via SSH to a remote system [remote1], and then connecting to another remote system [remote2] which remote1 has connectivity to, but my Windows system doesn't.

Here's an example that is working;

```
plink -ssh -pw password -batch root@remote1 ssh remote2 "sed -i 's/param=.*/param=newValue/' /root/test.txt"
```

This routine connects to remote1 via Plink, then connects to remote2 via `ssh`, then checks for a string `param=` and if it exists, replaces it with `param=newValue`. Again, this is working.

Here's what isn't working;

```
plink -ssh -pw password -batch root@remote1 ssh remote2 "grep -q -F 'param=newValue' /root/test.txt || echo 'export param=newValue' >> /root/test.txt"
```

This routine connects in the same way to remote1 and remote2, and then searches for `param=newValue` and if it doesn't exist, appends `param=newValue` to the end of the file. When I run this on Windows command line, it takes a couple seconds then exits with no errors, but the `test.txt` file is unchanged.

If I remote into remote1 using putty and then run the same command starting from `ssh remote2 "grep ...` then it does append the `test.txt` file.

I've tried escaping both `|` and `>`, but neither worked.

I've determined that the second half of the command is the part that is failing.

```
echo 'export param=newValue' >> /root/test.txt
```

More specifically, it appears to be the redirect portion, as I'm able to echo to the console when I remove the redirect.

Comment: Did you try moving the `ssh ...` part to a file and use `-m` switch of Plink?

Comment: Great idea using a file, that works without the -m switch. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I assume you have chosen to use an input redirection, right? Note that there are a difference though. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's say that the double-quotes are lost at some early stage (when executing Plink already), making the redirection happen on the first server already.

Consider providing the command to Plink using a different method.

- either using `-m` switch (recommended):

  ```
  plink -ssh -pw password -batch root@remote1 ssh remote2 -m command.txt
  ```

  With `command.txt` containing

  ```
  grep -q -F 'param=newValue' /root/test.txt || echo 'export param=newValue' >> /root/test.txt
  ```
- or using an input redirection:

  ```
  plink -ssh -pw password -batch -T root@remote1 ssh remote2 < command.txt
  ```

  Note the `-T` switch, that ensures that a shell is started in non-interactive mode - the same mode as used when the command is specified on command-line (like you original wanted) or using `-m` switch (as above).

  Normally, when you provide a command using an input redirection, an interactive shell session is started.

  Even with `-T` switch, the command is still executed using a "shell" SSH channel, contrary to "exec" SSH channel, when providing the command on command-line or using `-m` switch. So you experience some differences.
- Or you can store the command on either of the servers to a shell script.